# Tengo una duda, no se como resolver lo ultimo que me piden

Tags: python

Me pide escribir un programa principal con una función que, dada una lista de cadenas, devuelva una lista con todas las cadenas más largas, es decir, si dos o más cadenas miden lo mismo y son las más largas, la lista las contendrá a todas.

```
def llenar_lista(listaCadenas) :

    num_cadenas = int(input("Cuantas cadenas ingresara? : "))
    for i in range(num_cadenas): 
        cadena = input("Ingrese alguna cadena a la lista: ")
        listaCadenas.append(cadena)

def encontrar_palabra_mas_larga(listaCadenas):

    longitudCadena = []

    for cadena in listaCadenas:
        longitudCadena.append((len(cadena),cadena))
  
    print(longitudCadena)
    longitudCadena.sort()
    print(longitudCadena)

    return longitudCadena[-1][1]

**Programa principal**

listaCadenas = []

llenar_lista(listaCadenas)

longitudCadena = []

longitudCadena.append(encontrar_palabra_mas_larga(listaCadenas))
print(longitudCadena)
```

Comment: **Condición 1:** si dos o más cadenas miden lo mismo y son las más largas, la lista las contendrá a todas. **Condición 2:** no puedo hacer que cuando dos o mas cadenas miden lo mismo, y que ademas sean las mas largas, me devuelva una lista con estas,                                                                    no son lo contrario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok tu problema es fácil y nos podemos ayudar de distintas funciones como lo es la función `sorted()` la cual ordena una lista y acepta un parámetro llamado `key` el cual le indica a base de que va a ordenar la lista.

En primer lugar mejore la función `llenar_lista`, declarando la variable `listaCadenas` dentro de la función, pues declararla afuera no me parecia correcto, la función quedaría de esta forma:

```py
def llenar_lista() :
    listaCadenas = []
    num_cadenas = int(input("Cuantas cadenas ingresara? : "))
    for i in range(num_cadenas): 
        cadena = input("Ingrese alguna cadena a la lista: ")
        listaCadenas.append(cadena)
    return listaCadenas
```

Y la podemos llamar así

```py
listaCadenas = llenar_lista()
```

Para hacer encontrar la cadena mas larga y retorna varias en caso existan otras que tengan la misma longitud, usaremos la función `max()` y algunas compresiones de lista. Primero guardaremos una tupla `(longitud, palabra)` guardamos la longitud y la palabra, luego usaremos la función `max()`, para obtener el valor maximo de todas las tuplas, pero solo teniendo en cuenta su primer elemento (la longitud) eso lo haces con una función lambda en su parámetro `key`, finalmente hacemos una compresión de lista donde le decimos que guarde el segundo valor (la palabra) de la lista si su longitud es igual a la maxima.

```py
def encontrar_palabra_mas_larga(listaCadenas):
    longitudes = [(len(l),l) for l in listaCadenas]#guardamos las tuplas
    maxima_logn = max(longitudes, key=lambda l:l[0])#obtenemos la long maxima
    #cogemos los elementos cuya longitud sea igual a la maxima
    listaCadenas = [val for l,val in longitudes if l == maxima_logn[0]]
    
    return listaCadenas #retornamos
```

**Probamos**

```
#ejecutamos
listaCadenas = llenar_lista()

palabra = encontrar_palabra_mas_larga(listaCadenas)
print(palabra)
```

**Salida**

```
Cuantas cadenas ingresara? : 2
Ingrese alguna cadena a la lista: holas que hay
Ingrese alguna cadena a la lista: weey


#palabra mas larga-> ['holas que hay']
```

**Otra vez**

```
Cuantas cadenas ingresara? : 2
Ingrese alguna cadena a la lista: holas que hay
Ingrese alguna cadena a la lista: 12345 123 123

#palabras mas largas-> ['holas que hay', '12345 123 123']
```

Comment: Mi problemas no es que me devuelva la cadena mas larga, si no que cuando dos o más cadenas miden lo mismo y son las más largas, se tiene que devolver una lista que las contendrá a todas

Comment: Haa... bueno ahora edito la respuesta

Comment: @Cony listo :)..

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme! disculpa por molestarte aun, pero tengo una duda sobre el "val" para que es? o mejor dicho que es?

Comment: @Cony ho! bueno, creo que no lo explique, al recorrer una tupla, silo recorres de una forma *normal* te regresara `(13,'texto')` (es un ejemplo) pero al hacer `l, val` obtenemos cada valor el `13` corresponde a la variable `l` y `texto'` será el valor de la variable `val` pongo `val` haciendo referencia a la palabra *valor* solo lo hago para que sea intuitivo el termino de la variable

Answer (score 0):

En la pregunta (no sé si es enunciado de ejercicio) se pide " programa principal con una función que, dada una lista de cadenas, devuelva una lista con todas las cadenas más largas". Lo apunto porque en ningún caso te pide que devuelvas la longitud de la cadena, con lo que simplificas mucho el programa

Yo empezaría por algo así:

```
def mas_largas(lista_cadenas):
    """
    Parameters: lista de cadenas
    Returns: Una lista con las cadenas más largas
    """

    largo_max = 0   #   Aquí ira la longitud de la cadena más larga
    lista = []  #  Voy a crear una lista vacía ahora por si no hay cadenas en la lista
    for palabra in lista_cadenas:
        aux = len(palabra)  #  Guardo la longitud en una variable auxiliar para simplificar el código
        if aux > 0: # Compruebo que no es una cadena vacía
            if aux > largo_max:
                lista = [palabra]   #  Encontramos una cadena más larga
                largo_max = aux     #  Guardamos el nuevo valor máximo
            elif aux == largo_max:
                lista.append(palabra)   #  Como mide lo mismo que la más larga la añado a la lista
    if len(lista) == 0:
        print('No hay cadenas')
    return lista


cadenas = ['dada', 'una', 'lista', 'de', 'cadenas', 'carreta', 'caretas', 'largas']

print(mas_largas(cadenas))
```

Te pueden surgir un par de problemas:

- que todas las cadenas estén vacías, que es una de las comprobaciones que tienes en el código, si la cadena está vacia pasa a la siguiente
- que no quieras que se repita una misma cadena en la lista.

```
            elif aux == largo_max:
                if palabra not in lista:
                    lista.append(palabra)
```

Así antes de añadir una nueva cadena a la lista compruebas que no esté ya en ella.

Como la función devuelve la lista con todas las 'palabras' de la misma longitud puedes calcular la longitud en el cuerpo del programa con len(cadenas[0])

Answer (score 0):

Esta función recibe una lista de cadenas y retorna una lista con las cadenas de mayor largo.

```
def lista_mayores(cadenas):
    orden = sorted(cadenas, key=lambda x: -len(x))
    return [x for x in orden if len(x) == len(orden[0])]
```

Primero se ordena la lista de cadenas de mayor a menor largo. Para ordenar por largo usamos el parámetro `key`, entregando una función lambda que simplemente retorna el largo de la cadena, pero en negativo.

Con la lista ordenada, sólo queda seleccionar el primer elemento y los siguientes del mismo largo. Eso lo hace la comprensión de listas, seleccionando con `if` aquellos elementos de largo igual al primero.

**Demo**

```
lista_cadenas = [
    "cadena1",
    "cadena2",
    "x", "y", "z"
]
print(lista_mayores(lista_cadenas))
```

produce:

```
['cadena1', 'cadena2']
```